# returned string from input.getAttribute('value') is missing a character

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor, end-to-end

I am developing e2e-tests for an angular application but I've run into an issue. I am retrieving the value from an < input type="text" /> with the method .getAttribute('value') but it is missing a single character. I've checked the HTML properties of the element which holds the value and it displays it correctly. I've retraced the steps manually in the application and there it is displayed correctly as well. It seems very unlogical to me, but perhaps someone has had experience with this issue. Thanks in advance.

HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="schedule.cronValue" id="cronValue" disabled="disabled">
```

Protractor code to retrieve the value of the element:

```
//fill our CRON variable with the generated CRON value
        element(by.id('cronValue')).getAttribute('value').then(function(attr){
            CRON = attr;
        });
```

The expected output is the value from my database. The CRON value, is retrieved from the input type text.
Screenshot of the situation if needed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQofD.jpg

Console.log output:

```
Expected value:0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
CRON:0 0 0 1/ * ? *
```

As you can see, it is missing a '1' after the '/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to say without being able to reproduce the problem, but what I would try as a workaround is to use [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) and "evaluate" the value of the model:

```
element(by.id('cronValue')).evaluate('schedule.cronValue').then(function(value) {
    CRON = value;
});
```

If the `CRON` value would still have the same incorrect value - then, at least, you would know that this value is really set on the model and it is probably coming from the database as is.

Comment: When implementing your answer, the issue seems to persist. The output of CRON is now null, could this indicate an issue in the application itself?

Comment: @TomNijs thanks for trying this out. Could you also check that there are any other elements with `id="cronValue"`?

Comment: The id="cronValue" only occurs once, I just checked.

Comment: @TomNijs thanks, another strange quick check - can you add `browser.sleep(3000)` before trying to get the value of the input and see if it makes any difference? Thanks.

Comment: @TomNijs though I think this could be an issue with application itself - I mean the generated value is not something you expect due to a bug somewhere in the cron syntax generator..or somewhere on the way of transmitting or sanitizing that value from the database - just thoughts and wild guesses.

Comment: The browser.sleep(3000) brought the issue to the surface. I am clearing a text field in the cron generator, then doing .sendKeys, then retrieving the output. It appears the cron value does not update until clicking the save button which doesn't leave enough time to store the new value I suppose.